# Make a new site with Joomla

Tags: joomla

I just started a new job, where I have to make a Joomla landing page for a client in Joomla. I have never worked with Joomla before, so I have just seen some tutorials. I have set it up on my localhost, which is working fine, and I have access to the all the backend and CMS system.

But I would like to make a new practice site called "testpage". fx: http://localhost:8888/Joomla_3.5.1/testpage.php, so I can start from scratch and build up a site, instead of deleting things on the default template.

Does anyone knows how I can make a new site?

Best Regards

Comment: that link http://localhost:8888/Joomla_3.5.1/testpage.php is on YOUR computer is not visible to anyone outside by default. and what do you mean by "I can start from scratch and build up a site, "? you want build it without Joomla on plain PHP?

Comment: hehe I am aware of my localhost is only accessed by me.. :-) As it is now I get my Joomla backend through  localhost:8888/Joomla_3.5.1. I would like to start on a new page through Joomla. But I would like to make my own articles, menues and so on, instead of working on the default skin that is build in Joomla.

Comment: do you mean your own template? then maybe this: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go several ways:

- remove all files and flush the DB on you local computer and create a fresh install, but in the end of it you'll anyway have to choose the default template (Beez3 or alike)
- get a simplistic template (like https://github.com/gsuez/master-bootstrap-3 or http://www.blank.vc/) add it to your current install and start customising it; plus remove menus/blocks/content manually

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Am I thinking Joomla totally wrong. Lets say I have 10 clients, that needs 10 different Landing Pages. I thought that I should build 10 different landing pages. Excact like you would build a web project. Lets say I finish a job for Client 1. Then I have to start a new job for Klient 2. The same if you make a client_1.html, and make a page, and then a client_2.html and make the page in a webproject. Isnt it possible to have a collection in Joomla with all your projects?

Comment: you can have multiple templates = landing pages in your case - and they all can be activated for certain menu items / urls; https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Switching_templates